# Redirecting the date and time to a file when eth0 starts up

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am trying to write a script that redirects the date and time when eth0 comes up.
Here's the line with problem

```
up date '+UPTD %d-%m-%y/%H:%M' >> /home/abpit/network.log
```

But it doesn't write a single thing in the file! What am I doing wrong?

ubuntu version: 12.04 
File has now RWX permission, but still it doesn't have a single line in it. Also, eth0 is configured automatically .

Comment: You should add more info, like the file where you have put that line and your Ubuntu version/architecture. Also check the file has execution permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an encrypted home directory and eth0 is brought up before you log in (as it generally is if it is marked "auto") then the network.log file will be written under a directory which later is used as a mount point for your encrypted-home filesystem, rendering the file inaccessible. Don't write the date to a file in your home directory; use /var/log/.